# YouTube Videos playing too quickly, and without sound?

Tags: sound, video, youtube

new Ubuntu / Linux user here.

My first week of using and learning this operating system everything seemed to be working great.  Until Today.

YouTube videos in Firefox are speeding through very quickly and without sound.

My system received an update yesterday, I'm wondering if that could have caused the problem.

Please Help.

Comment: Do you know which "update" was downloaded? Also, how are you watching the videos? Minitube? Firefox? Google Chrome? Are you using Flash Player? [HTML5](http://youtube.com/html5)?

Comment: Check the sounds setting in the dash, and ensure that you are not using the HDMI as the sound device.

Comment: TSJNachos117, I'm using Firefox and the default flash player plugin.

Comment: My guess is a wrong bitrate (Intel sound?). I believe I saw something about fixing that with kernel parameters for snd-hda-intel at boot time

Comment: Charles Green, Thanks very much.  My sound settings were set to HDMI as you predicted.  Quick fix and everything is good to go again.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Please post this as an answer, and Vorpalstar please accept it. Thanks!